# Perl outputs too many columns

Tags: perl, match, lookup

I have one table of associated marker results and one table of disease markers. Both files have headers.

This is what the associated marker table looks like:

```
  snps_BCG24 gene_BCG24 statistic_BCG24 pvalue_BCG24    FDR_BCG24 beta_BCG24                 pair SharedOrUnique_BCG24 PercentileRank_BCG24 chr       cM   hg19pos    Diseasegene
rs11203184  C21orf128       -9.425704 4.008530e-12 2.501741e-05 -0.9199033 rs11203184_C21orf128      SharedSignalMO7         1.484874e-06  21  63.4452  43526430 notDiseasegene
rs11203184      C2CD2        2.290434 2.684575e-02 8.559484e-01  0.3114964     rs11203184_C2CD2    UniqueSignalBCG24         2.906046e-01  21  63.4452  43526430 notDiseasegene
```

This is what the disease marker table looks like:

```
Chr  hg19Pos  hg18Pos       rsID           SNPname               hg19UCSC               hg18UCSC startLoc   endLoc
1  1247494  1237357    rs12103  var_chr1_1247494   chr1:1247494-1247494   chr1:1237357-1237357  1147494  1347494
1  2502780  2492640  rs6667605  var_chr1_2502780   chr1:2502780-2502780
```

If the associated markers and the disease markers are on the same chromosome (associated column 9 == disease column 0, respectively) , I then want to check if the position of my associated marker (column 11 in associated table) falls within the start and end position of the disease markers (columns 7 and 8 in disease table).

If my associated markers are within that distance, I want to label that associated marker `"inLocus"`, otherwise, leave blank. The result output would be a file with two tab-delimited columns: 1) the name of every associated marker in the same order as the associated Marker table 2) `inLocus` or blank status for every marker in the associated marker table.

I wrote a perl script for this, but instead of outputting two columns (one for associated marker name and one for locus status), it outputs one column with marker name and a varying number of columns for the `"inLocus"` part--and not always the same number of columns. I don't know which marker is really `"inLocus"`, because each output column sometimes has a different status. What do I need to change in my code so that every marker in my list gets a definitive `inLocus` label? Would changing blank to print `"notLocus"` make a difference? Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data_file1="/Users/Me/AssociatedMarkers.txt";
my $data_file2="/Users/Me/DiseaseMarkers.txt";
open(Main, $data_file1) || die("Could not open file!");

my $Line = 0;
my $Line1 = 0;
my @main = 0;
my @loci = 0;

#Generate output files
open(Result, ">AssociatedMarkersInLocus.txt");
 print Result "SNP\tinLocus?\n";
foreach $Line (<Main>) {
    #remove new line character
    open(DiseaseMarkers, $data_file2) || die("Could not open file!");
    $Line =~ s/[\n\r]//g;
    @main = split(/\t/,$Line);
    print Result "@main[0]";
    foreach $Line1 (< DiseaseMarkers >) {
        $Line1 =~ s/[\n\r]//g;
        @loci = split(/\t/,$Line1);
        if ((@main[9] eq @loci[0])&&(@main[11]>=@loci[7])&&(@main[11]<@loci[8])){
            print Result "\tinlocus";
            close(DiseaseMarkers);
        }
    }
print Result "\n";
}
close(Result);  
#Report completion
print "Program AssociatedMarkers finished. \n";
```

Here are the results I'm getting:

```
SNP inLocus?                
MarkerNameHeader 
MarkerName1 inLocus     inLocus     inLocus
MarkerName2
MarkerName3             inLocus
MarkerName4 inLocus     inLocus     inLocus
MarkerName5 inLocus
```

Here is the results format I actually need:

```
MarkerName1 inLocus
MarkerName2
MarkerName3
MarkerName4 inLocus
```

Alternatively, if someone knows how to append inLocus information to my existing AssociatedMarkers file directly, that would be even better!

Comment: Without an input sample, we can't try anything.

Comment: Thanks, I added examples of both input files to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test with your sample data seemed to be good..

A little code review:

1. Declare variables as you need them. Globals can get confusing.
2. Use lexically scoped variables as file handles
3. Use three param open
4. Trying to close a filehandle inside the loop probably isn't what you wanted to do. I moved it out a few scopes
5. `last LINE` will break you out of the DiseaseMarkers file
6. `@foo[0]` should be `$foo[0]`

Nice to see you're not using `chop`/`chomp`! I fixed up your line-ending regexes to be even more portable..

Anyway, this should fix it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data_file1 = "/Users/Me/AssociatedMarkers.txt";
my $data_file2 = "/Users/Me/DiseaseMarkers.txt";

#Open data file and create file handle
open(my $mainfh, '<', $data_file1) or die "Could not open file! $!";

#define variables and constants
#Generate output files
open(my $resultfh, '>', "AssociatedMarkersInLocus.txt") or die "Could not open file for write! $!";
print $resultfh "SNP\tinLocus?\n";

foreach my $Line (<$mainfh>) {
    #remove new line character
    open(my $dmfh, '<', $data_file2) or die("Could not open file! $!");
    $Line =~ s/[\f\n\r]*$//g;
    my @main = split(/\t/, $Line);
    print $resultfh "$main[0]";

    my $has_locus = 0;

    LINE: foreach my $Line1 (<$dmfh>) {
        $Line1 =~ s/[\f\n\r]*$//g;
        my @loci = split(/\t/,$Line1);

        if (($main[9]  eq $loci[0])
            && ($main[11] >= $loci[7])
            && ($main[11]<$loci[8])) {

            $has_locus = 1;
            print $resultfh "\tinlocus";
            last LINE;
        }
    }

    if ($has_locus == 0) {
        print $resultfh "\tnolocus";
    }

    print $resultfh "\n";
    close($dmfh);
}

close($resultfh);
close($mainfh);

#Report completion
print "Program AssociatedMarkers finished.\n";
```

Comment: Hm, it kind of worked. "inLocus" only appears once now, but any marker that is not in the locus runs together on the same line instead of being its own line. Is there a way to change the blanks to "notLocus"? Maybe then every marker still gets its own line and its status is more definitive than a blank.

Comment: That did the trick! Clever use of true false too. And thanks for the Perl better practices tips.

Comment: I wish I could, but it says I need a 15 reputation to upvote, and I have 14 :(